# How to get rid of white space on each size of image in Bootstrap 4 image in Nav Bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I run this code my image, which is a small picture of myself and my wife is being padded on the right and left side with a thin white line. I can't quite figure out what I'm missing.

Not sure if I'm using the navbar correctly as I'm still trying to figure this stuff out.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-secondary navbar-dark fixed-top">

<!-- Brand/logo -->
<div class="container col-sm-12">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="http://dishtruck.com/joe_tn.jpg" alt="logo" <style width ="40px" height = "40px">
  </a>

  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Social Media</a>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav  ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: add a working snippet or fiddle

Comment: you could try using `padding: 0;` on the picture and /or the parent div, if you posted a working snippet or fiddle we could help more

Comment: Here is the codepin, I know there are a few other problems there. I've been just adding and adding and I have to clean it up, but you'll be able to see what I'm trying to do. https://codepen.io/joejhorn/pen/aVRyGp?editors=1010

Comment: The white space is in the image itself! (http://dishtruck.com/joe_tn.jpg) You have to edit this image.

Comment: well that would surely fix it, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!